# How do I create a check box using SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, box, iif

I've seen a lot of answers but none of the solutions/suggestions seem to be working. We've got a data field called 'meal' that comes back with a 'No' or 'Yes'
what i would like to appear in my table/data object is a check box with a check in it or an x or filled in or anything really so long as we can distinguish it from an empty check box - for a 'N' response.

I've tried windings, and fonts, and switch/iif statements and it keeps coming back with an error message.

Comment: Does the data come back with a No/Yes or does it come back with a Boolean/bit value? Is the value nullable? What expressions have you tried? Can you show the actual data value? What error do you get? Can you add more info please as it's difficult to diagnose without it

Comment: Check box is not a feature of SSRS. But you could try using multi valued parameter.

Comment: My data comes back with a yes/no in our system. In SSRS it simply says #Error on the report - it runs but doesn't give me anything.  What are mufti valued parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the other way you can use the 3 checkbox images `checked`,`unchecked` and `emptycheck` and embed them in your report. And then set the expression for showing the image depending on your value

```
 =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!meal.Value),"emptycheck",IIF(Fields!meal.Value,"checked","unchecked"))
```

This way you can remove the dependency of the font installation on the server. But you need 3 images embedded in report that can increase it's size but not by much as the image will be small.

Comment: so its safe to understand that there is no - inherent/built in "checkbox" in the ssrs functionality? nothing like a rectangle with an x or check in it to that's built in. (which if is true i find surprising as i can't imagine i'm the only person out there building reports who wants a graphic representation of a yes/no checkbox.

Comment: May be that is unavailable in `SSRS` because it is reporting tool and in reports you don't make interaction with `UI` . Reports are meant to show the data for your analysis not to change the data. I know you just want to show that `checkbox` but if you think about it the `checkboxs` main functionality is to provide the interaction with user, may be that's  why any `UI` control which capable of interaction with user are not available in the `SSRS`.

Comment: If yo don't want to go with the image `checkbox` then you can always use different colors  in report to show your three  conditions and somewhere in report header or top of the report show the description of color for which color indicates what.

Comment: I am using SSRS to create reporting based on data tracked by users. Doesn't that data need to be graphical representation of what is in the database. The checkbox isn't used to change the data in the report but to simply display the columns that are a Yes vs No in the system (as requested by our users). -- but Yes, we are offering the use the option the Y/N if they don't approve it we will use a graphic/color.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the font **Arial Unicode MS** it has *checked boxes* and *unchecked boxes* and you can reference the values needed. One caveat is that this font has to be installed on the ssrs server.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!UIStatus.Value) ,"■",
IIF(Fields!UIStatus.Value=0,"",
IIF(Fields!UIStatus.Value=1,"●",
IIF(Fields!UIStatus.Value=2,"◯",
"-"))))
```